# c++ boost asio timeout for blocking connect

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I have a C++ boost client that does a blocking connect and processes the message once it receives a response. I am facing a strange issue.

```
tcp::resolver::query query(tcp::v6(), this->host, port,tcp::resolver::query::v4_mapped);
iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
socket = new tcp::socket(io_service);
socket->connect(*iterator);
```

I tried to connect to a machine that was not reachable by ping6 (but was IPV6 enabled). Still, I didn't get any error while trying to resolve the query in line-2. As a result of this, it takes too much time while attempting a connection before giving an error. My questions:-

1) Is it possible to timeout on a blocking connect from asio? I cannot switch to async mode of operation.

2) How come I don't get an error while it resolves an unreachable host?

Any advice would be very much helpful

Answer (score 1):

Timeouts are the wrong place for synchronous methods, there's a lengthy [discussion](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/2832) in the asio ticket tracker.

> I cannot switch to async mode of
>   operation.

I find this highly unlikely given the timeout requirement, post the rest of your code and explain why you cannot use asynchronous operations.

Comment: @Sam..Thanks for a quick response. Actually, timeout is not a requirement. The main issue is that I get an iterator without error while querying for an unreachable host. As a result, the socket takes about 5 minutes(blocking) before giving an error

"A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable host"

Comment: Oh and I forgot to add that I see this behavior when specifying hostname in an IPV6 format.

Comment: Check the validity of the tcp::resolver::iterator after your resolve call by comparing it to a default constructed iterator.

Comment: @Sam..I tried to compare it this way:- 

tcp::resolver::iterator defaultEnd;
boost::system::error_code ec;
iterator = resolver.resolve(query,ec);
if (iterator == defaultEnd){
    wcerr << L"V6 successful without errorcode, but possible unknown host" << endl;
 return;
}

So, I compared the resolved iterator with default constructed one. I assume this is the correct way of comparison. But, it didn't succeed. I still get a "valid" iterator, that fails when used in a socket.

Comment: if you get a valid resolver::iterator then I suggest using async_connect with a timer if you don't like the synchronous connect        behavior.

Comment: What is the way to do it with asynchronous operations?

Answer (score -1):

When this question was asked, I guess ASIO did not have any example on how to accomplish what the OP needed, that is to timeout a blocking operation such as a blocking socket operation. Now there exists examples to show you exactly how to do this. the example seems long, but that is because it is WELL commented. It shows how to use the ioservice in a 'one shot' kind of mode.

I think the example is a great solution. The other solutions here break portability and don't take advantage of ioservice. if portability is not important and the ioservice seems like to much overhead --THEN-- you should not be using ASIO. No matter what, you will have an ioservice created (almost all ASIO functionality depends on it, even sync sockets) so, take advantage of it.

[ASIO example of timeout on blocking call](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/blocking_udp_client.cpp)

The ASIO documentation has been updated, so check it out for new examples on how to overcome some of the 'gotchas' ASIO use to have.

Comment: The example is about asynchronous operations, which is not what the OP asked for. I believe that is the reason someone downvoted this answer.