# It takes quite a moment for socket.read_some to return after socket.close has been called, in linux

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp, boost-asio

I'm using Boost.Asio as a simple socket library.

When I open a socket, I create a thread which keeps reading on that socket, and returns when the socket has been closed, or some other errors occured.

```
while((read = socket->read_some(buf, ec)) != 0) {
    // deal with bytes read
}
```

This code works well on Windows and Mac. However with linux, when the socket is closed from the main thread, it takes quite long time for `socket::read_some` to return - I found it's more than 2 minutes.

Is there anything I can do to improve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the reason: in Linux if you close a socket with socket::close, the socket is ***not*** closed. You ***must*** close a socket ***gracefully*** to close it ***successfully***.

```
socket->shutdown(shutdown_both); // add this
socket->close();
```

Comment: such problem doesn't exist on Windows/Mac.

Answer (score 2):

If you desire [cancel-ability](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/cancel/overload1.html), use asynchronous sockets. Don't use synchronous methods such as `read_some`. This has been discussed ad infinitum on the asio-users mailing list. There's also a [ticket](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/2832) on the boost bug tracker discussing it.

Also see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515281/c-boost-asio-timeout-for-blocking-connect/3516861#3516861) to a similar question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, according to my experience, with synchronous sockets it's still possible to have cancel-ability. Because read_some is supposed to return when error occurs on the socket. I've found a solution to this issue, see my answer below.